# How to refresh parent page after closing popup window in jQUERY?

Tags: php, jquery, mysql

I will send the value from child to parent after closing child window parent window will be reoload

Answer (score 0):

try 
`window.location.reload()`.

You can put it on the button to close the child window as `onclick="window.location.reload();return(false)"`